# Show that there is a non-zero constant $a$ such that $T_1(v)=aT_2(v)$ for all $v\in R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T_1$ and $T_2$ be two linear transformations from $R^n$ to $R^1$. If $ker(T_1)=ker(T_2)$, show that there is a non-zero constant $a$ such that $T_1(v)=aT_2(v)$ for all $v\in R^n$

> My Attempt-
>
> > Analysis: I need to achieve $T_1(v)=aT_2(v)$, that is $Av=aBv$
> >
> > Since $T_1$ and $T_2$ are mappings from $R^n$ to $R^1$, they must both be $1\ X\  n$ row  matrices. (Not sure how this will help.)
> >
> > Let the standard matrix for $T_1$ and $T_2$ be A and B respectively. Therefore, $ker(T_1)$ is the solution space of $Ax=0$ and similarily, $ker(T_2)$ is the solution space of $Bx=0$

I am not making any progress. Can anyone guide me in the right direction? Thanks Stack!@ Owe you one again and again.

Comment: Per chance you could try $a=T_1(1)/T_2(1)$?And use the fact that $Ker(T_1)=Ker(T_2)$ is either =$R^n$ or =$R^{n-1}$.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217752/let-l-and-t-be-two-linear-functionals-on-a-real-vector-space-v-such-that-lv

Comment: @awllower I can't rmemeber learning that Ker(T1)=Ker(T2) is either R^n or R^n-1. Can you show me a quick proof of that, is that is convenient? or maybe link me to a similar question. Thanks!

Comment: It was not supposed to be 1, but any generator of the complement of the kernel of the transformations. Sorry for that error.

Comment: I still don't quite understand. What is a generator? I am beginning my course in linear algebra haha. Sorry and thanks!@

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We consider two cases: If $\ker T_1 = \mathbb R^n$, we have $T_1 = 0$, and by $\ker T_2 = \mathbb R^n$ also $T_2 = 0$. Then $a = 1$ will do.

Otherwise, $\ker T_1$ is a $n-1$ dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^n$, let $x \in \mathbb R^n \setminus \ker T_1$. As $\ker T_1$ is $(n-1)$-dimensional, we have $\ker T_1 \oplus \langle x \rangle = \mathbb R^n$. We have $T_2(x) \ne 0$, as $x \not\in \ker T_2 = \ker T_1$, now let $a := \frac{T_1(x)}{T_2(x)}$. Let $y \in \mathbb R^n$, then $y$ can be written as $y = u + \lambda x$ with $u \in \ker T_1$, $\lambda \in \mathbb R$. We have 
\begin{align*}
  T_1(y) &= T_1(u) + \lambda T_1(x)\\
         &= \lambda T_1(x)\\
         &= \lambda a T_2(x)\\
         &= a T_2(u) + a\lambda T_2(x)\\
         &= aT_2(u+ \lambda x)\\
         &= a T_2(y).
\end{align*}
As $y$ was arbitrary, $T_1 = aT_2$.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$
T_1(x)=v_1\cdot x,\  T_2(x)=v_2\cdot x \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n
$$
for some $v_1,v_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Since
$$
\ker(T_1)=v_1^\perp=\ker(T_2)=v_2^\perp,
$$
it follows that $v_2=a v_1$ for some nonzero real constant $a$. Hence for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have
$$
T_2(x)=a(v_1\cdot x)=aT_1(x).
$$

Comment: Is that inverted T a symbol for transpose?

Comment: No, it means the orthogonal complement of the subspace generated by that vector, at least so I suppose.

Comment: For a subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ the notation $U^\perp$ stands for the orthogonal complement of $U$, i.e. $U^\perp=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n:\ x\cdot u=0 \quad \forall\ u \in U\}$.

Comment: Nice geometric interpretation!

Comment: Ok this looks like what I am looking for, but just one last problem haha, either I forgot, or this was not on my textbook, but $$
\ker(T_1)=v_1^\perp=\ker(T_2)=v_2^\perp,
$$
 I don't understand.

Comment: @SingaporeanDude. Since $T_i(x)=v_i\cdot x$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, it follows that $\ker(T_i)=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n:\ v_i\cdot x=0\}=v_i^\perp$. It should be clearer now I guess!

Answer (score 1):

If $\dim( \ker( T_1))=n$ is easy. So assume $\dim( \ker( T_1))\neq n \Rightarrow T_1 \neq0$. 
The exercise suggest to define $\alpha$ as $\alpha=\dfrac{T_1(u)}{T_2(u)}$ for some $u$ with $T_1(u)\neq 0$. 
If $T_1(v)\neq 0$ then $v-\dfrac{T_1(v)}{T_1(u)}u \in \ker( T_1)=\ker( T_2)$. 
Thus $T_2\left(v-\dfrac{T_1(v)}{T_1(u)}u\right)=0 \Rightarrow T_2(v)=\dfrac{T_1(v)}{T_1(u)}T_2(u)=\dfrac{1}{\alpha}T_1(v) \Rightarrow T_1(v)=\alpha T_2(v).$